# Agile Opportunist & Cunning Bard combo

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, bard

How does the Combo Agile Opportunist and Cunning Bard work?

Some people say you can only get opportunity attacks when an enemy triggers the OA. So you can't slide your ally with power/skill x and let swing his sword with agile Opportunist?

Answer (score 2):

Forced movement never provokes opportunity actions.

However, agile opportunity allows for you to make a melee basic attack *as an immediate reaction* which is not an opportunity action. You can absolutely use it with the Cunning Bard's sliding shenanigans.

The only catch here is it cannot be the ally's turn as they would not be allowed to take an immediate action on their turn.

Comment: Ty :) Made my day

Comment: @KeepSmilin make sure you're nice when you talk to your DM about this. The rules aren't a bludgeon.